# What is meant by " a basis is diagonal"?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, definition, quantum-entanglement, quantum-computer

I am trying to understand Schmidt decomposition. I am stuck in one sentence here. See the example picture.

[image: See the picture here]

Here, I can understand everything except the line "For both
HA and HB the Schmidt basis is diagonal (Hadamard) basis." Can anyone help to understand what the author tried to tell here by using this line?

Comment: Please do not post images of text.

Comment: Where is this excerpt from?

Comment: @TobiasFünke why? Is it against the community rule? I was not aware of it. I have no other option to present my doubts here otherwise sharing the snip of the part...

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Elements of Quantum Computation and Quantum Communication by Anirban Pathak

Comment: @INDRANILMAITI transcribing such a short text is not a problem, especially when as you said it's only a very specific part that you don't understand

Comment: You can type it by hand and use MathJax for equations.

Answer (score 2):

"diagonal basis" is non-standard terminology.

On the other hand, "Hadamard basis" usually refers to the basis given by
$$
\lvert +\rangle =\frac{\lvert 0\rangle  + \lvert 1\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}
\ ,\quad 
\lvert -\rangle =\frac{\lvert 0\rangle  - \lvert 1\rangle }{\sqrt{2}}\ ,
$$

which is indeed the Schmidt basis of the state in the example for both Alice (with Hilbert space $H_A$) and Bob (with Hilbert space $H_B$).